# How we can attach a file in Azure DevOps email job status noifications

Tags: azure-devops

I have few pipelines in Azure DevOps and some jobs are generating few files during build process. I want to send a mail to all team members with the same file as an attachment.
I'm using Azure Email report extension to send mails.
Can someone please help me how can I attach the file to mail notification to all team members.

Comment: Just checking in to see whether this issue is still blocking you now? Any update for this issue?

Answer (score 0):

We cannot attach a file in the email notification, as a workaround, we could install the extension [Send Email](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rvo.SendEmailTask&ssr=false#overview) to send email and add the attachment.

In the end of your pipeline definition -> Add a task `Send email`-> configure required options.

To delivery the artifact files by the Send Email task, you can select the Add Attachment option and specify absolute path for the attachment:

[image]

**Update1**

We could also refer to this [doc](https://github.com/TotalALM/VSTS-Tasks/tree/master/Tasks/Email) to use email task to send email with the attachment.
Note: We could not send email for a azure DevOps team group via these task, you could also submit your [user voice](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/idea/post.html?space=21) on this website